# How to load firestore collection to Vuex State?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

My goal is to load a firestore collection into the Vuex state and use it for multiple pages. I was trying to follow :
[How to get collection from firestore and set to vuex state when the app is rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942596/how-to-get-collection-from-firestore-and-set-to-vuex-state-when-the-app-is-rende)

I followed this post and either I am missing something or possibly the code is outdated? I am very new to Vuex so I could be doing something wrong but I am not sure.

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const db = require('../components/fbInit')


Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categories: []
  },
  actions: {
    fetchCategories({ commit }) {
      db.collection('one').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log('cannot find')
          //this.$router.push('/HelloWorld')
        } else {
          this.loading = false;
          var categories = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            categories.push(doc.data());
          });

          commit("setCategories", categories);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setCategories(state, val) {
      state.categories = val;
    }
  }
});

store.dispatch("fetchCategories");

export default store;
```

**One.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-row justify-center ma-12">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name">{{category.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

export default {
  computed: {
    categories() {
      return this.$store.state.categories;
    },

    ...mapGetters([])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchCatagories"])
  }
};
</script>
```

I tested to see if the firestore is connected and it displayed its contents. But I am getting this error:            Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function.

I have never been able to load my firestore collection into the Vuex store state and load it. Again I am new to using vuex so any help will be greatly appreciated

TLDR; Goal: Load firestore collection('One'), Store it in Vuex state, Use Vuex store to load the same data on multiple pages without having to call the data on every page.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have added any getters.  It will be a property of the Vuex store just like actions and mutations.  When you use mapGetters, it should also contain the name of the getters to be mapped.

Comment: I did have one but took it out after it didn't work. But my first hurdle is trying to figure out why I get the error: db.collection is not a function. I thought that if the collection was loaded I could still grab the data from my computed: categories function. I am very new to Vuex...

Comment: I see.  It sounds like Firestore isn't being imported properly then.  You also have a mix of Common.js and ES6 modules.  What about:  import db from '../components/fbInit'

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Both of your suggestions were great. Thanks mate!

Comment: Don't feel dumb.  It's easy for anyone to make the most basic of mistakes.

Comment: Do you know how I can make the data update instantly if I change a field in the firestore database? Like the page will load the new info on any update/change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205886/discussion-between-yewla-and-justin-levine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### store/index.js

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
....
getters: {
    categories (state) {
        return state.categories;
    }
},
....
});
```

#### One.vue

```
export default {
....
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['categories'])
    },
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`const db = require('../components/fbInit')` might be your problem here. In a firestore/vue project I own, my db is declared as:

```js
import firebase from '../firebase';
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: this is how it is declared in my fbInit file. But thanks.